# add ID and class to new added row in jquery DataTable 1.10.11

Tags: jquery, datatable

I want to add Id to newly added row in datatable but didn't found any way yet in latest dataTable to set ID of new row. I've used following code to add new row. How can I set this row's ID?

```
var owner = $('#owner').DataTable();
owner.row.add([
  resp.id,
  firstName,
  lastName,
  email,
  city,
  country,
  html
  ]).draw();
```

Comment: Use row render callback to set id

Comment: can you please give me an example or any useful link from where i can get help. Thanks!

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html

Answer (score 0):

For add ID to tr element you con use `rowId` and especify the column that contain your id.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var owner = $('#example').DataTable(
{
columns: [
{data:"id"},{data:"position"},{data:"office"},{data:"age"},{data:"date"},{data:"salary"}
],
rowId: 'id'
});

var new_object = { id:'0004', position: 'Developer', office: "Peru", age: 25, date: "2016/03/25", salary: "$ 58.200" };

owner.row.add(
  new_object
  ).draw();

} );
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/27/